# WCF method called twice in Mac OS Firefox Browser

Tags: c#, wcf

I am calling wcf service method from web application. It is working fine in all browsers in Windows OS and calling once. But in Mac OS Firefox browser, it's calling twice.

**My SVC.cs file ServiceBehavior is**

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = 
                       InstanceContextMode.PerCall, 
                       ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, 
                       Namespace ="")]
```

**My Svc interface is**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "StoreXMLInfo", 
          BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
          ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
          RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
XMLInfoPO StoreXMLInfo(Stream xmlstring);
```

**This is the Code that calls the service**

```
            string returnstring = null;    

            WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);    //wcf service uri
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parameters);   //parameters to service method
            Stream os = null;               
    try
    {
                webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length; 
                os = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
                os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); 
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
               // catch block
            }
            finally
            {
                if (os != null)
                {
                    os.Close();
                }
            }

            try
            {                    
                using (var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
                        returnstring = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
                    }
                    catch (Exception exl)
                    {
                      // catch block
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException exc)
            {
                 // catch block
            }
```

Can any one help me to fix this bug?

Comment: Please provide the code that calls the service.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not the browser that makes two requests to the webapplication?

Comment: I am sure that it is the browser issue because the process is completed once and the mail is send to the user.Again the same process is doing second time in Mac OS firefox browser alone.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing is happening with me. I'm using Firefox but on Windows OS. I'm making a call to the delegate for ServerCertificateValidationCallback and it's firing twice. After reading this post I tested the same in IE and the request fires only once. Not sure why it fires twice in Firefox. Something to do with Firefox for sure.